# Struck on unf_ext 0.0.8 with native extensions Chaskiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently facing this issue on Chaskiq bot which is based on ruby and rails. While installing dependencies with bundler, I got stuck at
unf_ext 0.0.8.

First I encounter the ruby version error that 2.7.6 is not supported, only 2.7.5 is
then Installed the 2.7.5
ran this cmd

```
bundle install
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6poY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most probably because of missing the version number of "sassc" in the dependencies file. Consider adding the version number manually.

Edit Gemfile

```
sudo nano Gemfile
```

replace the following line:

```
gem "sassc"
```

with:

```
gem "sassc", "~> 2.1.0"
```

Comment: Can i use the newer version sassc?

Comment: Ofcourse you can